# jQuery element.data() syntax. How do I know what `$(this)` is?

Tags: jquery, syntax

I have the following jQuery variable:

```
var confirmbox=$('<div></div>')
        .data({'defaultText': 'This action cannot be reversed. Are you sure you wish to do this?',
               'defaultButtons': {  Yes : function() { $(this).dialog('close');}, 
                                    No  : function() { $(this).dialog('close');}
               }
        });
```

I want to set `confirmbox.html()` to `confirmbox.data('defaultText')`.

```
confirmbox.html(confirmbox.data('defaultText'));//this works
confirmbox.html($(this).data('defaultText'));//this fails. Why?
```

And the same failing syntax now works here:

```
confirmbox.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: $(this).data('defaultButtons'),
            close: function(){
                $(this).html($(this).data('defaultText')); //working here. Why?
                $(this).dialog('option','buttons',$(this).data('defaultButtons'));
            }
        });
```

I think that I don't understand what `$(this)` is referring to in particular contexts.  How do I tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is a reference to the current context object. In your example that fails, `this` is probably referring to the `window` object (or whatever the next immediate enclosing context is, if not window). If `window` had its own attached `defaultText` data, for example, you'd be passing *that* into `.html()`.

But since `.html()` is designed to also take a function as an argument, within that function, `this` will refer to the `confirmbox` context. Try it like this:

```
confirmbox.html( function(){
  // this now refers to confirmbox
  return $(this).data('defaultText');
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `return $(this).data('defaultText');`?

Answer (score 2):

Like you said, it's all about the context.
When the dialog.close() function is executed, the this object points to the dialog instance, as a result $(this) refers to the jQuery dialog object. If you're executing

```
confirmbox.html($(this).data('defaultText'));//this fails. Why?
```

in a global context, this doesnt have that meaning. it refers to the document.window object, not your dialog instance.

Comment: +1 exactly. And the fix is, erm, to just do it the first way.

Answer (score 1):

In `confirmbox.dialog`, `this` refers to the the `confirmbox` object.  That's why `$(this)` worked.

In the line `confirmbox.html($(this).data('defaultText'));`, `this` has no context, and is just set to `window`.

I'm not very good at explaining things, but I hope this helped.