# Update the price based on quantity picked from select menu per form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am doing a simple calculation where I take an initial product price and based on a quantity (select element) I multiply that total price by the value selected.

When I make a selection I would like the total price to be updated. So for the product below, if I select value 5 the total price should now be 50.

I also want to make sure that only the form where the select is being changed is updated and not both total prices.

http://jsfiddle.net/o9uLm17z/2/

```js
var quantity = $('.product-item option:selected').find(":selected").val();
    var price = $('.total-price').text();
    
    $('.total-price').val(quantity * price);
    
    $('.product-select').change(function() {
        var quantity = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        var price = $('.total-price').val();
    
        $('.total-price').val(quantity * price);
    });
```

```html
    <form method="post" action="/" class="product-item">
      <p>
        Product One
      </p>
      <div class="total-price">10</div>
      <select name="quantity" class="product-select" tabindex="1">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: `parseFloat` is your friend. Also, `div`s don't have values, so `$('.total-price').val();` won't work (you have correct above that though...).

Comment: Are you able to modify the HTML so that the item's base price is not the same div that you want the item's final price to be shown? For example, add it as a data attribute to the select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your missing is the base value of the price and parsing it to an integer/float.
You also need to get the closest form then find .total-price class to print the output.
Here's a JSFIDDLE for you.

```js
jQuery('.product-select').on('change', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var quantity = parseInt(el.val());
    var price = parseInt(el.closest('.product-item').find('[name="price"]').val());
    el.closest('.product-item').find('.total-price').text(quantity * price);
});
```

```css
form {
  background: teal;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="/" class="product-item">
  <p>
    Product One
  </p>
  <input type="hidden" value="10" name="price">
  <div class="total-price">10</div>
  <select name="quantity" class="product-select" tabindex="1">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
</form>

<form method="post" action="/" class="product-item">
  <p>
    Product Two
  </p>
  <input type="hidden" value="10" name="price">
  <div class="total-price">40</div>
  <select name="quantity" class="product-select" tabindex="1">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify the HTML so that your base price and total price don't occupy the same div, I was able to add data-price to the select and just use a universal function to simplify.

```js
$.generate_price = function(){
$(".product-select").each(function(){
      $(this).prev(".total-price").html(parseFloat($(this).data("price")) * parseInt( $(this).find("option:selected").val()));
    });
}    
    
    $('.product-select').change(function() {
        $.generate_price();
    });
    
    $.generate_price();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="/" class="product-item">
      <p>
        Product One
      </p>
      <div class="total-price"></div>
      <select data-price="10" name="quantity" class="product-select" tabindex="1">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      </select>
      
            <p>
        Product Two
      </p>
      <div class="total-price"></div>
      <select data-price="15" name="quantity" class="product-select" tabindex="1">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Bind the form to [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event

   ```
   $(".product-item").on('change',...
   ```
2. Assign the select as second parameter ([`event.data`](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/) or [`$(this)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4694594/2813224))

   ```
   ...'.product-select',...
   ```
3. Third parameter is the [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

   ```
   ...function(e) {...
   ```
4. Get the [value](http://api.jquery.com/val/) of the select and convert it into a [real number](https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/)

   ```
   var qty = Number($(this).val());
   ```
5. Get the value of the output and convert it into a real number

   ```
   Number($(this).prev('.total-price').val());
   ```
6. Finally, get the product of both elements and assign it to the value of the output

   ```
   $(this).prev('.total-price').val(qty * prc);
   ```

Remember [form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements#Value) (inputs, selects, outputs, etc) store their values as a string "3" does not equal 3. In order to isolate each output/select pair use `$(this)`[`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to specify the output in relation to the select. Also for semantics label and output elements were used instead of divs. The output is a special form control because it can store a value or have text content and it has other useful features, see this article on the [output element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output).

```js
$(".product-item").on('change', '.product-select', function(e) {
  var qty = Number($(this).val());
  var prc = Number($(this).prev('.total-price').val());
  $(this).prev('.total-price').val(qty * prc);
});
```

```css
select {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/" class="product-item">
  <label>
        Product One
    </label> <br> Total Price: <output class="total-price" value='10'>10</output>
  <select name="quantity" class="product-select" tabindex="1">
    <option value='' selected>Select Quantity</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <label>
        Product Two
   </label> <br> Total Price: <output class="total-price" value='10'>10</output>
  <select name="quantity" class="product-select" tabindex="1">
    <option value='' selected>Select Quantity</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following
it works with me:

**HTML :**

```
 <form method="post" action="/" class="product-item">
        <p>
          Product One
        </p>
        <strong> Unit Price:</strong><div class="product1-Item-price">10</div>
        <strong> Total Price:</strong><div class="product1-total-price">10</div>
        <select id="product1" onchange="calculteTotal(event)" name="quantity" class="product-select" tabindex="1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
      </form>

      <form method="post" action="/" class="product-item">
        <p>
          Product Two
        </p>
        <strong> Unit Price:</strong><div class="product2-Item-price">10</div>
        <strong> Total Price:</strong> <div class="product2-total-price">40</div>
        <select  id="product2" onchange="calculteTotal(event)" name="quantity" class="product-select" tabindex="1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
      </form>
```

**JS**

```
function calculteTotal(evt){
var price = $("." + evt.target.id + "-Item-price").text();
var quantity = $('#'+evt.target.id).val();
$("." + evt.target.id + "-total-price").text(quantity * price)
}
```